# can not curl large files

Tags: curl

I am using the following curl syntax to copy a file to another server and it is working as expected.

```
curl -F file=@/home/abc.txt.gz http://1.2.3.4/upload.php
```

But if the file abc.txt.gz is more than 2 or 3 MB in size, it fails with error code returned as 1. Is file size limitation part of curl command or it is just the network issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limitation is most likely in the web server's PHP configuration.

Comment: I changed the upload_max_filesize from 2M to 10M in php.ini and it worked.